# Can you mix assemblies compiled in different versions of .Net?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

We have a set of assemblies that have been compiled as.Net 3.5 (built using VS2008). I now have VS2010 and I'd like to see what .Net 4.0 has to offer.

Do I have to recompile the 3.5 assemblies into 4.0 before I can include them in my project? My first attempts to reference the old libraries doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assemblies based on older versions of .NET can be referenced by a newer version but not the other way around i.e. NET 4.0 assembly can use .NET 3.5, 3.0, 2 etc assemblies, but a .NET 3.5 assembly can't reference a .NET 4.0 assembly.

Note that you can only run a NET 4.0 assembly if it is sinstalled on that machine.
Also some behaviour between NET versions has changed - significantly NET1.0 to NET 2 for instance.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if it was dependant upon the project type as it seemed to work for WCF service projects and MVC3 projects but didn't work for a class library. Maybe it was "Fat Fingers" clicking the wrong button.